# Python request GET for collections for shopify issue pagination

Tags: python, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

Hello I have a code in Python to request smart collections. I have more than 500 categories to read by the Python script. The script is perfectly fine and just one line is wrong:

The error comes because the original code says:

```
collectionResponse = requests.get(f"{shop_url}.json?limit=250&page={page}", headers=headers)
```

Then that cause error. To test the code I replace with:

```
collectionResponse = requests.get(f"{shop_url}.json?limit=250", headers=headers)
```

And it works without errors but of course it shows only 250. Apparently this is wrong `&page={page}` if I remove the download to the file very good. What other thing is available there? Removing `&page={page}` only reads the first page, in other words the first 250 smart collections but if I want the rest of the other 500 collections not.. How can I modify that line to be able to read the other 250 of the second page? Apparently 250 is the maximum instances manage shopify if I’m not wrong that is the reason.

Comment: Did you set the page variable?

Comment: ‘page’ is not working for smart collections. I could not find anything. What I did to solve the issue is another secondary script that calls the script until that downloads 50 collections only, but calling it many times in a loop and append the csv until are collections are populated.